# Getting error, Error: Cannot find module ‘express’ after npm install

Tags: windows-7, express, installation

I am new to both Node JS and express, and I have just installed npm in Windows 7.

I have installed express using the global flag:

```
npm install -g express
```

This sucessfully installs express in `C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express`, and adds `C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm` to my path.

However, using express in the command line is not successful. Any command starting with express tells me it cannot find the command to execute:

```
 'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

Looking in the installation folder, I can't find an executable file either (an .exe or a .cmd). Googling past questions shows that the node_modules folder (at least in past versions) should contain both an express folder (which I have) and a `.bin` folder, which contains `express.cmd`. I don't appear to have the `.bin` folder.

`npm --version` gives me **1.4.3**. Express version looks to be **3.0.0**

I've also tried installing it locally, and I've tried running `npm cache clean` and reinstalling. Neither method changes the situation: there's nothing executable in the node_modules folder.

**Am I installing express incorrectly? If so, why does it not include an executable file?**

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I ran into the same problem on Windows 8.1. The express.cmd is not created, but I found the text file:

```
C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express\Readme.md
```

It suggests to run this:

```
npm install -g express-generator@3
```

Which will download more stuff.

After that you can use **express** on the windows command prompt. It will be in your path (
C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\npm)

Edit:

`express-generator@3` is now updated to `express-generator@4`,
so use this instead,

```
npm install -g express-generator@4
```

The answer isn't complete, because the modules are installed in `C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\npm` directory as stated above, and you cannot always access any module without, 1) linking it to your current project or 2) explicityly defining the `NODE_PATH` system variable pointing your node to the right place in the system.

**First method,**

After installing the module (`express` in our case), you can link it to your current project by going to your current project directory using cmd and executing below command,

```
npm link express
```

You will get a message like this if it is successfully linked,

> D:\Project\node_modules\express ->
>   C:\Users\Sufiyan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express

(you cannot link directories without running cmd with Administrator privileges)

The second option is to create or update  NODE_PATH system variable pointing your node to the right place in the system. Read [this](http://rusticode.com/2012/09/17/error-cannot-find-module-express/) for details.

Also read this official Node.js documentation regarding the issue,

http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

Comment: That fixed it for me as well. nodejs v0.10.26 on windows 8.1

Comment: Had same issue on Linux, so it is not Windows only. Solution worked, thank you.

Comment: This also worked for me (Windows 10, Express 4.13.4, Node 6.2.2).

Answer (score 8):

This is all you need to do:

```
C:\node> npm install -g express-generator
```

You can find this and much more at [this detailed start up tutorial](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/).

Comment: So you gave me a -1 for restructuring a helpful answer? Something that a true newbie would want to know? I mean that's OK but what a way to make me want to contribute!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful DonieM!

Answer (score 5):

To fix this you need to use:

npm install -g express-generator@3

It has been updated from the previous command:

npm install -g express

Answer (score 2):

Just be aware that the version as return by the express --version command will be the version of express-generator, not express.

Comment: How can i uninstall it? Because I've installed  it without the -g

Comment: if you did then just delete local node modules folder or only its folder inside that

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, Seems though we use -g it's ignored.

I just copied contents of `MyProject/source/vendor` to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Copy only needed folders inside node_modules (like: express, express-generator, bower, yo, gulp and packages that should be in PATH).

---

*This problem really bothers everyone (or windows users?), npm programmers should solve it!*

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd as administrator. It solved the 'express' not found problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

`npm link express` to link express from any directory to your project directory were node is, by default when you run `npm install express` it would be installed in `C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express`, so you don't have to install express and other frameworks required to install each time in your project directory, instead you can point to your node i.e where you have your application.