# installed express globally on Windows 7 but still see 'command not found'

Tags: node.js

Based on this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-express-a-node-js-framework-and-set-up-socket-io-on-a-vps, I have tried two methods to install express globally on windows 7 and none of them work for me.

```
<In Git bash>
npm install -g express

<In windows cmd>
npm install -g express
```

After the installation is done, I run the following command:

```
$ express
```

'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

The following directory is installed on windows 7:
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006804/getting-error-error-cannot-find-module-express-after-npm-install

Answer (score 1):

The article of digitalocean is rather old. You need [express-generator](https://github.com/expressjs/generator) now, not the `express`. So try:

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

Also, take a look at the [generator docs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).