# Persisting error: express is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to install express on my windows 8 machine. I have already tried the following commands:

```
npm install -g express
npm install -g express-generator@4
```

Barring above, i also tried installing globally using Admin privileges and also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006804/getting-error-error-cannot-find-module-express-after-npm-install) .

My node_modules directory does not show the express folder either.

I also tried Updating node and restarting the terminal/machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `npm install -g express-generator@4`

Since you installed the package `express-generator@4` globally, so you'll find the executable `express` in directory `%APPDATA%\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin\` .

> My node_modules directory does not show the express folder either.

If you want it in your local project's node modules, install the package without global flag `-g` and you'll have both `express` folder inside `node_modules` dir and an executable named `express` inside the directory `node_modules/.bin`.

Comment: Tried the above too. Still no progress, cli still prompts the same error.